# In mysql, does join or left join guarantee native row order?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have two tables: Count and Price

```
Count
+----------+-------+
|  fruit   | count |
+----------+-------+
| apple    |     1 |
| pinapple |     1 |
| pear     |     1 |
| grava    |     1 |
+----------+-------+
```

```
Price
+----------+-------+
|  fruit   | price |
+----------+-------+
| pinapple |    20 |
| apple    |    10 |
| pear     |    15 |
| grava    |     5 |
+----------+-------+
```

When I join the two table by

```
select * from Count c join Price p on c.fruit = p.fruit;
```

Is the returned row order gurantee to be like Count `(apple->pinapple->pear->grava)`, or like
Price `(pinapple->apple->pear->grava)`?

I don't want to use `order by fruit` but use Count's native row order instead. In this example, because two table overlap, I can use left join or right join to query. Is there any method to gurantee the result returns like Count? `(apple->pinapple->pear->grava)`

Comment: MySQL does not guarantee an order unless you specify one. You can't rely on 'native row order' because that can change in unexpected ways as MySQL works with the database.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Could you point out a reference or a document for that?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6051) on [dba.se], specifically the first answer. The official standards documents are [here](https://blog.ansi.org/sql-standard-iso-iec-9075-2023-ansi-x3-135/), but at $200+ per volume I don't have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, assuming the default storage engine of InnoDB, the order rows are returned if you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause in your query is the order in which they rows are read from the index of the first joined table (the clustered index counts as an index when doing index-scans or table-scans).

Demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id serial primary key, x int, y int, index(x));

mysql> insert into mytable values (1, 30, 100), (2, 20, 200), (3, 10, 300);

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+------+------+
| id | x    | y    |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |   30 |  100 |
|  2 |   20 |  200 |
|  3 |   10 |  300 |
+----+------+------+
```

This is expected. The table-scan uses the order of the clustered index (i.e. PRIMARY).

```
mysql> select id, x from mytable;
+----+------+
| id | x    |
+----+------+
|  3 |   10 |
|  2 |   20 |
|  1 |   30 |
+----+------+
```

Without specifying an `ORDER BY`, the natural order changed. Why? The optimizer chose the index on column `x` because it formed a covering index for the columns requested in the query. So it returned rows as it read them from that index, in the index order.

```
mysql> explain select id, x from mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: mytable
   partitions: NULL
         type: index        <-- indicates an index-scan
possible_keys: NULL
          key: x            <-- this identifies the index
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 3
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index  <-- indicates it's a covering index
```

This is not a documented rule. It's just the result of the way the InnoDB storage engine is implemented. A different storage engine may have a different natural order. The implementation of InnoDB may also be changed in the future.

There is no obligation for the vendor to guarantee the natural order of rows remains consistent.

Suppose they were to change the code in InnoDB so the natural order is different in some future version of the software. This would not qualify as breaking backward compatibility, because the old order of rows was never a documented or supported behavior.

None of this changes if you use inner join or outer join.

If you want a specific order of rows returned by a query, you must use `ORDER BY`. InnoDB will still read the rows in the order of the index it chooses, but if necessary, MySQL will then re-sort the result according to the order you requested.

```
mysql> select id, x from mytable order by id;
+----+------+
| id | x    |
+----+------+
|  1 |   30 |
|  2 |   20 |
|  3 |   10 |
+----+------+
```